# Creating radio button group Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am creating *radio button group*. Which is not available in-build in Xamarin.iOS. However I have created 2 radio buttons but both independent(not acting like radio button group)
I need only 1 option to be selected at a time & need **text associated selected radio button**.
My code

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    var rBtn = new MyRadioButton(new CGPoint(20, 70), "Generic");
    this.Add(rBtn);
    var rBtn2 = new MyRadioButton(new CGPoint(160, 70), "Subject");
    this.Add(rBtn2);
}
```

MyRadioButton used avobe.

```
 public class MyRadioButton : UIView
    {
    private CircleView circleView;
    private UILabel lbTitle;

    public bool State {
        get {
            return circleView.State;
        }
        set {
            circleView.State = value;
        }
    }

    public MyRadioButton (CGPoint pt,string title)
    {
        this.Frame = new CGRect (pt, new CGSize (150, 30));
        circleView = new CircleView (new CGRect(0, 0, 30, 30));
        lbTitle = new UILabel (new CGRect (30, 0, 120, 30));
        lbTitle.Text = title;
        lbTitle.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        this.AddSubview (circleView);
        this.AddSubview (lbTitle);
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(1,0,0,0.3f);
        UITapGestureRecognizer tapGR = new UITapGestureRecognizer (() => {
            State = !State;
        });
        this.AddGestureRecognizer (tapGR);
    }
    }

    class CircleView : UIView
    {
    private bool state = false;
    public bool State { 
        get {
            return state;
        }
        set {
            state = value;
            this.SetNeedsDisplay ();
        }
    }

    public CircleView (CGRect frame)
    {
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        this.Frame = frame;
    }

    public override void Draw (CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
    {
        CGContext con = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();

        float padding = 5;
        con.AddEllipseInRect (new CGRect (padding, padding, rect.Width - 2 * padding, rect.Height - 2 * padding));
        con.StrokePath ();

        if (state) {
            float insidePadding = 8;
            con.AddEllipseInRect (new CGRect (insidePadding, insidePadding, rect.Width - 2 * insidePadding, rect.Height - 2 * insidePadding));
            con.FillPath ();
        }
    }
    }
```

See output screenshot below where I am **able to select both radio button**. They are not behaving like group

[image]

Comment: Are you able to explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve with the radio button group? As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Question title itself telling, I need radio button group & for reference purpose i have attached screenshot. Don't be ridiculous @lain Smith

Comment: Its hard to be ridiculous when you don't spend the time to write a question. So you have made the radio button group, are you trying to only have one option selected for both radio buttons? Sorry for the ridiculous questions.

Comment: Can you post your code? for the radio button groups you have created?

Comment: Look at my updated question.